# Combine the update and insert query in same statement in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

is it possible to combine the update and insert query in same statement apart from transactions and stored procedure.

For ex:At a time i want to update the records in table1 as well as insert the data in table2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using

```
multi_query
```

You can fin more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Something like this

```
 $link = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
 }


$testquery .= "INSERT INTO x (`agent_name`, `job_number`, `job_value`, `points_value`) SELECT agent_name, job_number, job_value, points_value FROM jobs WHERE YEAR(booked_date) = $current_year && WEEKOFYEAR(booked_date) = $weeknum;";

$testquery .= "SELECT agent_name, SUM(job_value), SUM(points_value) FROM leaderboard GROUP BY agent_name ORDER BY SUM(points_value) DESC";

mysqli_multi_query($link, $testquery) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($link) . "<hr>\nQuery: $testquery");
```

Comment: can you tel me sample query

Comment: i need sample query bcoz i tried many ways.but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type it and automatically mysqli will read it. like

```
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO x (`name`,`age`) VALUES ('me','21')");
@mysql_query("UPDATE y SET `status`='verified' WHERE `name`='me'");
```